# Can I simplify "It would appear to be the case that ..." to "It would appear that ..."

Tags: word-usage

The sentence I'm looking at is:

> From the similarities and differences discussed above, it would appear to be the case that many people prefer travelling by car for reasons of comfort and safety.`

And I'd like to change it to:

> From the similarities and differences discussed above, it would appear that many people prefer travelling by car for reasons of comfort and safety.`

The phrase "to be the case" in the first sentence seems a little redundant to me, because it doesn't say anything new. But I'm not sure if I can use "appear" that way in the second sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your sentences are acceptable. I agree that "to be the case" is superfluous.

But why not take it a step further? ... "Similarities and differences" are both what is revealed by "comparisons". "Discussed above" means, I presume, what you've just been talking about. The cleft construction with "it" is pompously indirect. Why 'appears'?-- do you mean the evidence is misleading, or just that it's not conclusive? "For reasons of" is verbose. And there's an awful lot of nouns ...  So

> These comparisons suggest that many people prefer to travel by car because it's safer and more comfortable.